# Drag and Drop Navigation

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create a drag and drop navigation for my site. The idea is to take a heading (ie, about us, home, contact etc) and drag and drop it into a space, which then leads you to a different page (kind of like this http://www.carbonstudio.co.uk/) I love this jquery but i have no idea how to start something like this.

Comment: Your first step with *any* problem like this is to chew out a smaller problem from the big one. Not only are you more likely to be able to solve the smaller problem, it's more likely to get a useful answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To use Drag and Drop you can use [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Than the only code you need to use drag and drop is:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

To use [jQuery UI Droppable see this link](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Than an example would be:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```